# Angular 2 - Access a variable from component to out side of a class( No parent, child relationship)

Tags: angular

I'm trying to access a variable from a component to outside of a class and there is no relationship(parent/child) to that component. I did some R&D kind of thing but couldn't find the way to do it. If any one have idea please help me.

For example component is like:
BankAccountComponent.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-bank-account',
  templateUrl: './app-bank.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-bank.component.scss']
export class BankAccountComponent {
  accountFlag: false;
  changeFlag(){
    this.accountFlag = true;
  }
}
```

out side class like:
CustomValidator.ts

```js
export class CustomValidators extends Validators { 
static bankAccValidator(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null {
//Here I need to use that component variable i.e accountFlag
return null;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Services are designed for same, (Dependency Injection)

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
//define a variable
someVariable = "xyz";
}
```

Provide this service in parent module or root module of the components (app.module.ts)

inject the service in components

```
one.component.ts
constructor(private someService: SomeService) {

}
// update the variable here
this.someService.someVariable = "Value Changed"

two.component.ts
constructor(private someService: SomeService) {}
// updated variable can be accessed here
console.log(this.someService.someVariable);
```

Comment: Could be a better way in case of many variables, but in case of a single variable may be global variable would be fine, isn't it?

Comment: Because global variables have global scope, they are visible, and mutable, by anything that runs on the page. That introduces implicit coupling between all code running on the page; everything could interact with everything.

That runs contrary to the concept of encapsulation. If your code and variables are local in scope, it's easier to reason about the thing; only those parts of the code that can access the variable may have changed it.

When it comes to variables attached to the window object, you never know where they have been, or who has touched them.

Comment: Strongly agree. Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is the correct way to achieve this but you can access the variable by declaring globally and exporting from there like below -

```
export const accountFlag: false;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bank-account',
  templateUrl: './app-bank.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-bank.component.scss']
export class BankAccountComponent {
   constructor(){
       console.log(accountFlag);
   }
}


export class CustomValidators extends Validators { 
static bankAccValidator(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null {
console.log(accountFlag);
return null;
}
```

Comment: @SpRaju const is just a type here, you can use either `var,let` etc

Comment: Yes you'r correct, it's working but don't know this is right approach or not. Any way thank you.

Comment: If you multiple similar variables then this is not a recommended approach, but for once you can use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in diffrent ways:
 1. Create service and define the variable in service and use in any componets.
 2. Keep value in session storage:

```
          sessionStorage.getItem('VariableName');
          sessionStorage.setItem('VariableName', "test");
```